# How can I end a property with a question mark in C#?

Tags: c#, special-characters

I'm sure this information is available in the C# spec, but I thought I'd give y'all a chance to set me straight. Why won't this code compile?

```
namespace DataObjects
{
    class QuestionMark
    {
        public bool Possible? {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make my boolean properties end in a question mark? I think it would add to readability and be nifty.

Let's hear it!

Comment: Aside of why it's not allowed in C#, I don't think it helps with the readability. `if (IsPossible) then` reads like a sentence. `if (Possible?) then` feels like you put a question mark in the middle of that same sentence. `Possible? = false` reads even weirder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually don't think it has much to do with nullable types as that is easy to determine base on a type declaration.  It probably has more to do with the ternary operator.  If you had a variable with a ? at the end you wouldn't be able to determine the difference between a normal reference to a variable and a ternery call. For example:

```
int a;
bool b?;
a = b? ? 15 : 22;
```

Comment: Good point. Add the null coalescing operator and you could run into  "b???0" if your spacing was bad. It's the same reason you can't have a variable named "b+".

Comment: This looks like the most likely reason it was in the spec. Thanks for the informative answer!

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you just name it `IsPossible` ?
That is clear, consice and no subject for confusion.

The question mark is a special character, and is used to indicate that a value type is 'nullable'.

Comment: I'm aware of nullable<T> types, like int?. Can't the compiler tell the difference between a type and a name?

Comment: foo?bar:baz. Ternary operator or label with a question mark in it followed by some expression baz?

Answer (score 2):

From [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm):

```
identifier-start-character::
    letter-character
    _ (the underscore character U+005F)

identifier-part-characters::
    identifier-part-character
    identifier-part-characters identifier-part-character

identifier-part-character::
    letter-character
    decimal-digit-character
    connecting-character
    combining-character
    formatting-character

letter-character::
    A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl
    A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl

combining-character::
    A Unicode character of classes Mn or Mc
    A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of classes Mn or Mc

decimal-digit-character::
    A Unicode character of the class Nd
    A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Nd

connecting-character::
    A Unicode character of the class Pc
    A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Pc

formatting-character::
    A Unicode character of the class Cf
    A unicode-escape-sequence representing a character of the class Cf
```

So identifiers are limited to containing only characters that are considered "letters" by the Unicode standard. "?" is a punctuation character (class Po).

Answer (score 0):

? is a special character in C#.  If it follows a type, it means the [type is nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: It has to follow a type not a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid to do so.

Is this a Rubyism? :-)